# Total Variation sign

Tags: total-variation

I read a form of total variation like this: $\sum\sqrt{||\nabla f||_2^{2}+^2}$

What does the plus and squred sign mean? Shouldn't it just be $\sum\sqrt{||\nabla f||_2^{2}}$ ?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-21-23-27668  In Methods Part, Step 3

Comment: Are you referring to equations (15) and (16) in the paper? The formula does not appear to be copied correctly in your question. Did you omit the $\epsilon$?

Comment: @littleO the equation 10 in this paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5155489/ Sorry I referred to the wrong paper. I think it does mean $\epsilon$. It should be the same as the equation(16) in the wrong paper. Thanks!